# AngularJS add value of checkboxes to an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="doc in providers">      
  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{doc.provider.Id}}" ng-false-value="" ng-model="ids"></td> 
</tr>

{{ids}}
```

i want to get the values of the checkboxes on an array

Comment: why not mark the one below as *the answer*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ng-true-value` only accepts strings so you'll need to use a workaround. This has been a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1199) for some time. In the meantime, you can do this:

Create an `ids` object in the controller like:

```
$scope.ids = {};
```

and change `ng-model` to reference a key in that object. You can use the default `true/false` checkbox values:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ids[doc.provider.Id]"></td>
```

Then you can loop over the keys in `ids` checking for `true`.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/Ugjvm/)

Answer (score 7):

I found that [this directive](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) provided the functionality I was looking for. The main problem I ran into with the more common solutions is that I have two arrays which I needed to store data compatible with a multi select list. The checklistModel directive provides this very basic functionality and works with multiple models.

Answer (score 5):

I will start by saying that I really don't like the options for doing this in angular.  I can't even say that this is better than the accepted answer, but it does keep the data in the model.

Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat='(index, doc) in provider'>
    <td><input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='{{doc.provider.Id}}' ng-model='ids[index]' /></td>
</tr>

<span ng-repeat='id in ids'>{{id}} </span>
```

Now just $watch the array value and filter when it changes in the controller (make sure to pass the object equality parameter):

```
$scope.ids = [];

$scope.updateIds = function() {
    $scope.ids = $scope.ids.filter(function(id) {
        return !!id;
    });
};

$scope.$watch('ids', $scope.updateIds, true);
```

When I started answering this question, I thought the most idiomatic options would be to add an ng-change directive on the input:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='{{doc.provider.Id}}' ng-model='ids[index]' ng-change='updateIds()'/>
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected.  The UI doesn't update properly when removing values.  I also want to point out that you can do this without the repeat directive:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='1' ng-model='ids.0' />
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='2' ng-model='ids.1' />
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='3' ng-model='ids.2' />
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='4' ng-model='ids.3' />
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='5' ng-model='ids.4' />
<input type='checkbox' ng-true-value='6' ng-model='ids.5' />
```

In this case, the $watch is definitely better than adding the ng-change to each input.  Finally, here is a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YantP7MdRHgt3DDDayUX). The $watch function does end up running twice each time a box is checked or unchecked, but that's really how it has to be!